# I'm a newbie of deep-learning..! Why my CRNN model's accuracy is too low?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is my code, and image of training accuracy

```
# !curl -L -s -o '/content/ESC-50-master-16k.tar' 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1hFt-qarD_Ihjb3jW7pd3tje2pcY5tfuJ&confirm=t'

# !tar -xvf "ESC-50-master-16k.tar"

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import librosa

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from glob import glob
```

Device Configuration

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

Load ESC-50 Data & Preprocess

```
metadata = pd.read_csv("./ESC-50-master-16k/meta/esc50.csv")
wav_list = sorted(glob("./ESC-50-master-16k/resample/\*.wav"))

def spec_to_image(spec, eps=1e-6):
mean = spec.mean()
std = spec.std()
spec_norm = (spec - mean) / (std + eps)
spec_min, spec_max = spec_norm.min(), spec_norm.max()
spec_scaled = 255 \* (spec_norm - spec_min) / (spec_max - spec_min)
spec_scaled = spec_scaled.astype(np.uint8)
return spec_scaled

class esc50dataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, wavlist, metadata):
self.labels = np.array(metadata.target).astype(int)
self.audio = \[\]
for f in wavlist:
wav, sr = librosa.load(f, sr=None)
spec=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(wav, sr=sr, n_fft=1024, hop_length=640, n_mels=126) # \[126,126\]
spec_db=librosa.power_to_db(spec,top_db=80)
spec_image = np.expand_dims(spec_to_image(spec_db), axis=0)
self.audio.append(spec_image.tolist())
self.audio = np.array(self.audio)
def __len__(self):
return len(self.audio)
def __getitem__(self, idx):
return self.audio\[idx\], self.labels\[idx\]

dataset = esc50dataset(wav_list, metadata)
features = dataset\[:\]\[0\]
labels = dataset\[:\]\[1\]
```

train test split

```
train_size = 0.7
val_size = 0.5

`make train set`

split_id = int(len(features) \* train_size) # 2000 \* 0.7 = 1400
train_features, remain_features = features\[:split_id\], features\[split_id:\] # train_features = 1400, remain_features = 600
train_labels, remain_labels = labels\[:split_id\], labels\[split_id:\] # train_labels = 1400, remain_labels = 600

`make val and test set`

split_val_id = int(len(remain_features) \* val_size) # 600 \* 0.5 = 300
val_features, test_features = remain_features\[:split_val_id\], remain_features\[split_val_id:\] # val_features = 300, test_features = 300
val_labels, test_labels = remain_labels\[:split_val_id\], remain_labels\[split_val_id:\] # val_labels = 300, test_labels = 300

`define batch size`

batch_size = 32

`create tensor datasets`

train_set = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(train_features), torch.from_numpy(train_labels))
valid_set = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(val_features), torch.from_numpy(val_labels))
test_set = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(test_features), torch.from_numpy(test_labels))

`create dataloaders`

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size) # 1400 / 32
val_loader = DataLoader(valid_set, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size) # 300 / 32
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size) # 300 / 32

`Model Hyperparameter`

in_channel = features\[0\].shape\[0\] # in_channel = 1
max_pool_kernel = 3

hidden_size = 256
hidden_layers = 10
output_classes = labels.max() + 1 # output_classes = 50
dropout = 0.25
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 10
```

Model

```
class CRNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channel, hidden_size, hidden_layers, output_classes, dropout):
super(CRNN, self).__init__()
self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.CNN_layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channel, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=max_pool_kernel),  # 32, 42, 42
        )
        self.CNN_layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=max_pool_kernel),  # 64, 14, 14
        )
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=64, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=hidden_layers, batch_first=True)        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_classes) 
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        # print("start : {}".format(x))
        x = self.CNN_layer1(x)  # 1, 126, 126 -> 32, 42, 42
        # print("after CNN_1 : {}".format(x))
        x = self.CNN_layer2(x)  # 32, 42, 42 -> 64, 14, 14
        # print("after CNN_2 : {}".format(x))
        x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1, 64)  # 64, 14, 14 -> 12544 , x.size(0) = Batchsize = 32
        # print("after reshape : {}".format(x))
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.hidden_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) # torch.size([10, 32(batch_size), 512])
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.hidden_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) # torch.size([10, 32(batch_size), 512])
        x, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        # print("after lstm : {}".format(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # print("after dropout : {}".format(x))
        x = self.fc(x[:,-1,:])
        # print("after fc : {}".format(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        # print("after sigmoid : {}".format(x))
        return x
```

model initialization

```
model = CRNN(in_channel, hidden_size, hidden_layers, output_classes, dropout)
```

Criterion & Optimizer

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

Train

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

tr_loss = \[\]
tr_acc = \[\]
v_loss = \[\]
v_acc = \[\]

best_valid_loss = torch.inf
best_epoch = 0
model = model.to(device)
epochloop = tqdm(range(num_epochs), position=0, desc='Training', leave=True)

for epoch in epochloop:
model.train()
train_loss = 0
train_acc = 0

epochloop.set_postfix_str(f'Training epoch {epoch}/{len(epochloop)}') # visualize
for idx, (audio, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
audio, label = audio.to(device), label.to(device)
out = model(audio)
\_, pred = torch.max(out.data, 1)

    # acc
    train_acc += (pred==label).sum()
    
    # loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = criterion(out, label)
    train_loss += loss.item()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Validation

```
model.eval()
val_loss = 0
val_acc = 0

with torch.no_grad():
for idx, (audio, label) in enumerate(val_loader):
epochloop.set_postfix_str(f'Validation batch {idx}/{len(val_loader)}')
audio, label = audio.to(device), label.to(device)

          # forward pass
          out = model(audio)
          _, pred = torch.max(out.data, 1)
    
          # acc
          val_acc += (pred==label).sum()
    
          # loss
          loss = criterion(out, label)
          val_loss += loss.item()

model.train()
```

save model if validation loss decrease

```
if val_loss / len(valid_set) \<= best_valid_loss:
best_valid_loss = val_loss / len(val_loader)
best_epoch = epoch
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "LSTM_epoch\_{}.pth".format(epoch))
```

print epoch loss & accuracy

```
print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs} | Train Loss: {train_loss / len(train_loader):.3f} Train Acc: {train_acc / len(train_set) \* 100}% | Val Loss: {val_loss / len(val_loader):.3f} Val Acc: {val_acc / len(valid_set) \* 100}%')
tr_loss.append(train_loss / len(train_loader))
tr_acc.append(train_acc.cpu().numpy() / len(train_set) \* 100)
v_loss.append(val_loss / len(val_loader))
v_acc.append(val_acc.cpu().numpy() / len(valid_set) \* 100)
```

[my training accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A398N.png)

Please tell me why my training accuracy is too low..

Answer (score 0):

By your dataset, I'm inferring you are trying to identify sound data, and you are applying a CRNN. If you go to the repo Have you seen [the repo](https://github.com/karolpiczak/ESC-50) for this dataset you will find a table with the accuracy for each method, the CRNN has about 60% accuracy, this is not so great since other methods achieve more than 95%.

You might need to change your model to get better results. Check the table you will find also some models with code

A bit difficult to give you an answer without reviewing your whole code, and re-running the model. Given this situation, I would suggest you create a Github repo, with appropriate the requirements.txt file for your code.

Even more helpful, and more likely to be answered would be if your code is in a jupyter notebook, and you can show the results of your loss curve and epochs. Your results could be more understandable shown like the output of tensorboard.

Hope this helps you to get some answers